# Problem installing our manage package

Tags: apex, managed-package, error, install

Good day everyone,

I have a manage package in my org. It is working well. But just this morning, when I try to install the package I've seen this error for the first time.

```
"Something has gone wrong. afterRender threw an error in 'markup://aura:html' [afterRender threw an error in 'markup://aura:html' [afterRender threw an error in 'markup://aura:if' [afterRender threw an error in 'markup://ui:label' [afterRender threw an error in 'markup://aura:html' [afterRender threw an error in 'markup://aura:expression' [afterRender threw an error in 'markup://aura:html' [afterRender threw an error in 'markup://ui:inputRadio' [TypeError: a is null]]]]]]]] Failing descriptor: {markup://aura:html}. Please try again."
```

What is the possible reason of this ? I've already install this package many times before but now I can't. Please help.

Comment: Once you acknowledge the erroneous error the really error should be displayed afterwards. Usually due to a dependency

Comment: @Eric you are right. I didn't seen it until I close the first error. Thank you...

Comment: Added it as the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you acknowledge the erroneous error the really error should be displayed afterwards. Usually due to a dependency

Answer (score 0):

For newly created org, the locker service feature will be active by default.If you are trying to install your lightning package into a newly created org, this can be the reason. Deactivating the locker service might be a temporary fix for this.

You can deactivate it by going to **Build > Critical Updates**